# How to set different fo:block (inside <fo:table-cell>) attribute (ex: font-weight="bold") inside a table (table is dynamic) based upon xml value

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Below is my sample xml; number of `<Item>..</Item>` will be fixed (4) only; and `<ItemName>..</ItemName>` contents are also going to be the same; only `<ItemValue> ..</ItemValue>`, will be changing.
Below is the sample xml:

```
<Header>
  <Item>
    <ItemName><![CDATA[ItemName1]]></ItemName>
    <ItemValue><![CDATA[ItemValue1]]></ItemValue>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <ItemName><![CDATA[ItemName2]]></ItemName>
   <ItemValue><![ItemValue2]]></ItemValue>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <ItemName><![CDATA[ItemName3]]></ItemName>
   <ItemValue><![CDATA[ItemValue3]]></ItemValue>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <ItemName><![CDATA[ItemName4]]></ItemName>
   <ItemValue><![CDATA[ItemValue4]]></ItemValue>
  </Item>
</Header>
```

Now here i want to represent the ItemName(s) and ItemValue(s) provided that the last two set which are  (ItemName3,ItemValue3) and (ItemName4,ItemValue4), I wanted to show in bold font; obviously we can do this by traversing one by one with setting the fo:block font-weight="bold" as per need.
But here I want to use this inside a loop ;
Tried sample code like below:

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
  <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="35mm"/>
   <fo:table-body>
     <xsl:for-each select="Header/Item">
       <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="ItemName != 'ItemName3' or ItemName != 'ItemName4'">
               <fo:block>
                 <xsl:value-of select="ItemName"/>
               </fo:block>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                  <xsl:value-of select="ItemName"/>
                 </fo:block>    
              </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>             
             </fo:table-cell>
             <fo:table-cell>
               <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="ItemName != 'ItemName3' or ItemName != 'ItemName4'">
                 <fo:block>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ItemValue"/>
                 </fo:block>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ItemValue"/>
                  </fo:block>   
                </xsl:otherwise>    
                 </xsl:choose>
             </fo:table-cell>
           </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-body>
```

But then fop is complaining about fo:table-cell is missing child element ; so what could be the possible solution for this?

**Update**

added xsl:choose in the above code now it is not complaining but also not getting expected result. Instead all text is getting printed in normal font-weight only.

As suggested had tried code piece also (posted logic for bold only)

```
<xsl:if test="ItemName != 'ItemName3' or ItemName != 'ItemName4'">
  <xsl:attribute name="font-weight" select="'bold'"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Though no error but hadn't got any expected result too.

Comment: Please use correctly formatted xslt. 
In you example there are closing quotes missing. And when-elements  should be inside choose-elements.

Comment: @siebe-jongebloed I found missing ' ' for xsl:when comparison updated the; can you please let me know what else I had miss? That because may be of typo; as fop-2.8 is not complaining for any syntax.

Comment: Is the input really in CDATA?

Comment: @KevinBrown yes.

Answer (score 1):

Your last change:

```
<xsl:if test="ItemName != 'ItemName3' or ItemName != 'ItemName4'">
  <xsl:attribute name="font-weight" select="'bold'"/>
</xsl:if>
```

will always be true because of your `or`. I.e.

- if `ItemName='ItemName1'` it wil be true for both
- if `ItemName='ItemName2'` it wil be true for both
- if `ItemName='ItemName3'` it wil be true for `ItemName != 'ItemName4'`
- if `ItemName='ItemName4'` it wil be true for `ItemName != 'ItemName3'`

**xslt 2.0**
Try this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Header/Item">
  <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:if test="ItemName=('ItemName3','ItemName4')">
          <xsl:attribute name="font-weight" select="'bold'"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="ItemName"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**xslt 1.0**

```
<xsl:if test="ItemName='ItemName3' or ItemName='ItemName4'">
  <xsl:attribute name="font-weight" select="'bold'"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: SystemId Unknown; Line #156; Column #77; Expected ), but found: ,
(Location of error unknown)java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.xpath.objects.XString cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.apache.xpath.objects.XString is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
[ERROR] FOP - Exception <org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.xml.transform.Transformer.setParameter(String, Object)" because "transformer" is null
getting this error

Comment: @RitoSarkar - If you're using FOP to process the XSLT, you're stuck with XSLT 1.0. Siebe's answer is 2.0 because you have the question tagged as 2.0. (I also think this answer, using a 2.0 processor, would output the opposite of what you want. It would add the font-weight attribute to Item's other than ItemName3 and ItemName4.)

Comment: Ok ; but it is not even doing the opposite as well; the effect of the font is not even being applied. @daniel-haley

Comment: @DanielHaley: Correct, my mistake....corrected it

Comment: <xsl:if test="ItemName=('ItemName3','ItemName4')"> still same error  

SystemId Unknown; Line #156; Column #72; Expected ), but found: ,
(Location of error unknown)java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.xpath.objects.XString cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.apache.xpath.objects.XString is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
[ERROR] FOP - Exception <org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke

Comment: As @DanielHaley explained, this is a 2.0 feature. 
Since you tagged your question as xslt 2.0 I still leave it like this, for others to use.

Comment: ok but what will be the solution I can look into it? I am using XSLT 2 and fop-2.8; so how I can achieve the goal now? And do you mean the provided syntax should work with xslt 2.0? Then seems like we are contradicting here because for me with xslt 2.0 it is not working.

Comment: What xslt engine do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253498/discussion-between-siebe-jongebloed-and-rito-sarkar).

Comment: Ok we can discuss over the chat. @siebe-jongebloed